# Redshift - Finding latest row with active flag

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying find all `cust_id` that have a value of `flag = 1`.

Using Redshift DB. I only want to extract rows that have flag = 1 but `sale_id` is the largest for a given `cust_id`

Given below is how my data looks like:

```
sale_id,cust_id,prod_name,flag
1001,101,prod_a,0
1002,101,prod_b,0
1003,102,prod_a,1
1004,102,prod_b,0
1005,102,prod_c,0
1006,103,prod_a,0
1007,104,prod_a,0
1008,104,prod_b,1
1009,105,prod_a,0
```

Expected output:

```
sale_id,cust_id,prod_name,flag
1008,104,prod_b,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you are only interested in the largest sale_id for any given cust_id. You need to extract that first with a subquery:

```
select max(sale_id) from table_name group by cust_id
```

Then use that to filter the table with those sale_id and the flag

```
select *
from table_name
where 
    sale_id in (select max(sale_id) from table_name group by cust_id)
    and flag = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In Redshift, you would typically approach this using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number(flag) over (partition by cust_id
                                    order by sale_id desc
                                   ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and flag = 1;
```